# Sending emails where Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses, rate-limiting

I am sending 10,000 emails per day.

So that emails do not end up in the spam, I decided to use the service of **Amazon SES**.

After testing, I saw that the service Amazon sends **700 emails per 27 minutes**. This is a very long time, given the fact that I'm posting every day on 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

All Amazon SES accounts have sending limits. There are two limits: a rate per second and a rate per rolling 24 hour period. You can read more about the sending limits here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-limits.html

If you exceeded your sending limit then the excess emails would have been rejected.

You can solve this by adjusting your code to respect the throttle rate for your account, or applying for an increased send rate: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/